# How to select only 1 row from a query result? like the 4th row

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code and am looking to make a sort of "quotes area" on my website. I want it to select 3 random quotes from my database everytime. I know about the function `rand(min,max)`, but how do I use it to select that exact row from the query?

```
require 'DB.php';
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '430123');
$db = mysql_select_db('bakery', $link);
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM quotes');
```

I could use a for loop and use `mysql_fetch_row()` for how much the number from `rand()` was, but that could be a bit inefficient maybe?

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Comment: thanks for the advice Jay Blanchard

Answer (score 4):

To get only the 4th row use `limit offset, number_of_records`

```
SELECT * FROM quotes
order by rand()
limit 3, 1
```

Comment: With RAND()? I'm confused.

Comment: @Strawberry ordering by rand() assigns each row a random number, and MySQL will then order those in ascending order, randomising the order the results are returned.  In this case, it would select everything in the quotes table, order it randomly and then return the 4th result in the set

Comment: But it's RAND, so what's the difference? This is astrology.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just could select all quotes and then use function [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to select your random quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can use ORDER BY rand().

eg.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM quotes ORDER BY rand() limit 3');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that returns an array of $count elements given a source array. You have to add support for avoiding duplicate quotes, but this does what you asked.

```
<?php
    require 'DB.php';    
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '430123');
    $db = mysql_select_db('bakery', $link);
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM quotes');
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    get_quotes($row,3);

   function get_quotes($source,$count) {
        $quotes = array();
        for ($i = 0;$i<$count;$i++) {
            $seed = rand(0,sizeof($source)-1);
            $quotes[] = $source[$seed];
        }
        return $quotes;        
    }
```

Maybe doing it in a query would be better, but I don't think that's what you asked for.